# transform point into raster (asc)

Tags: r, raster

I have longitude and latitude data of my populations (point with longitude and latitude) in csv format.

```
pop Longitude   Latitude
ALSZNRG 104.89575   40.175
EJNYG   103.22  41.62694444
ALSYSHT 106.5616667 40.15277778
HLS 106.0325    39.05391667
DK  106.5952778 40.42861111
ALSZCHE 105.8302778 39.47361111
WLTH    106.5616667 41.27472222
WLTQ    108.6825    40.72444444
WH  106.6636111 39.58166667
ALSY    101.7547222 39.28055556
```

I would like to conduct circuitscape analysis.
However, It requires the asc format for these points.
Furthermore, it also requires this asc format file should have the same header with resistance file (also asc format) one.
The resistance file for my analysis is as below:

```
NCOLS 276 
NROWS 96 
XLLCORNER 99 
YLLCORNER 38.5 
CELLSIZE 0.0416666666666667 
NODATA_value -9999
```

How could I perform this using R?
(I do not have ArcGIS)

Comment: You can use `raster::rasterize` to rasterize points if that is what you really need (seems odd). You can probably do the entire analysis in R with the `gdistance` package.

Comment: Circuitscape doesn't require .asc files for your point data; these can be expressed as a tab-delimited text file. Circuitscape does, however, require .asc files for the habitat and resistance files. The resistance file you have copied above isn't a resistance file - that's just the .asc file's header defining the extent, resolution etc. Could you please provide some more detail as to exactly what you need to do? Do you need to convert pre-existing .tif/raster files into .asc files? If so, I can help with that. As it stands, this question is too vague.

Comment: I should add - you can pass Circuitscape a .asc of your focal points (i.e. the points between which you wish to model connectivity). But make sure each patch of habitat has a unique number associated with it.